# obtener notas javascript

Tags: javascript

Esto comenzando con javascript y me cerraron la pregunta anterior quisiera saber que esta mal en este codigo corro el test y no me lo lee como buena

```js
function invertirLetras(frase) {
    // La funcion recibe un string "frase". Convertir las letras en minúsculas a mayúsculas y viceversa y devolver
    // la frase con dichos cambios.
    // TIP: Usar toLowerCase y toUpperCase
    // Para saber si un char es upper o lower, comparalo con el mismo char en upper o lower;
    // ej:
    //  'i' === 'i'.toLowerCase(); -> es lower;
    //  'I' === 'I'.toLowerCase()l -> no es lower;
    
    let cadena = "Hola!! , estoy muriendo!!!";
    let minusculas = cadena.toLowerCase();
    let mayusculas = cadena.toUpperCase();

    console.log("En minúscula: %s", minusculas);
    console.log("En mayúscula: %s", mayusculas);

};
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Según la descripción que hay en la función, lo que tienes que hacer que el parámetro de entrada "frase" detectar si es mayúscula o minúscula, en función de lo que sea hay que invertirla, es decir, si la entrada es mayúscula se convierte a mínuscula.

```js
 function invertirLetras(frase) {
            // La funcion recibe un string "frase". Convertir las letras en minúsculas a mayúsculas y viceversa y devolver
            // la frase con dichos cambios.
            // TIP: Usar toLowerCase y toUpperCase
            // Para saber si un char es upper o lower, comparalo con el mismo char en upper o lower;
            // ej:
            //  'i' === 'i'.toLowerCase(); -> es lower;
            //  'I' === 'I'.toLowerCase()l -> no es lower;
            
            let minusculas = frase.toLowerCase();
            let mayusculas = frase.toUpperCase();
              if(frase==minusculas){ //se comprueba si es minúscula
                console.log("Convierte de minúsculas a mayúsculas: ", mayusculas); // se pinta mayuscula
            }else{
                console.log("Convierte de mayúsculas a minúsculas: ", minusculas);
            }
            
        
        };
        
        invertirLetras("hola"); //Salida "HOLA"
        invertirLetras("HOLA"); //Salida "hola"
```

Comment: Este código no funciona si el string tiene mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Comment: @Emeeus antes de darme respuesta negativa, podrías comprobar que en el enunciado solo dice si la entrada es mayúscula o minúscula, en ningun momento dice lo que dices

Comment: La pregunta no es para nada clara, pero el ejemplo de la cadena es "Hola!! , estoy muriendo!!!", además como "TIP" indica la evaluación de char, no de frase.